# Problem with require module using passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have a rails module included for reference below that I have included using "require 'model_helper' at the bottom of my environment.rb file.

Everything works fine in development, but when I deploy to my nginx/passenger production environment I get an error that the method acts_as_notifiable defined in my model_helper is not found.  For some reason the model_helper is not loaded when starting with passenger.  The file is called model_helper.rb and is in the lib folder.

```
    module ActiveRecord
 module ModelHelper # module name
  def self.included(base)
   base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
   def acts_as_notifiable
    after_create :post_create
    has_one :notification, :as => :about, :dependent => :destroy


   end
   end
  def post_create
   Notification.create :user => user, :about => self unless user.nil?
  end

 end
 end

 ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ActiveRecord::ModelHelper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge the files in lib directory are not loaded automatically. RAILS includes the `lib` directory in the class path. You have to explicitly load the file if you need it. You can do so by:

Adding a `require` to the end of    `environment.rb`, i.e.

```
require `model_helper.rb`
```

**OR**

By adding a initializer file in the `config/initializers` directory, i.e.

**config/initializers/load_model_helper.rb**

```
require `model_helper.rb`
```

Comment: Thanks, the first does not work by the way in my particular configuration, but the second did.  

Thanks saved the day.  I have not used the initializers folder much before.